Is there a way to read more than one network packer for async_read for ssl websockets?
I want to know whether there is a way in C++ to do an async read on ssl websocket and return more than 1 network packet from network card if available?
Apparently its not available in boost::beast, I wander are there any alternatives or workarounds to this?

How is this different than writing a coroutine that does two async reads in succession, then returns both values?

The difference is async_read cost, effectively copying packet from network card is roughly 5us if you don't have kernel bypass. So if you can copy all (up to N ofc) packets to buffer(s), with 1 async read you save a lot of time @JaMiT

"SSL websocket" - but the underlying packets on the network card are TCP/IP.  All the boost websocket code that reads messages executes at a higher level, on the CPU.

What this has to do with my question? @MSalters

@EduardRostomyan: The reason it's not available in Boost is because the idea makes little sense. "Network packets" are IP packets. not websocket packets.

Ok, is it available outside of boost? Can I have a stream and do async read and more that 1 packet associated with that stream? @MSalters

The TCP layer already performs the optimization being requested here.

Have you tried using Boost.Asio. I think it's difficult but in Boost.asio you can have multiple packet management. Only downside is you need to setup your own buffer management and reading logic. In boost.asio you'll have more granular control of your IO operation, for asynchronous reads returning multiple network packets Boost.Asio allows manual buffer management. Did you tried it or should I give an answer on how to do so!!

You can use the Asio library directly without Boost. Asio provides lower-level control over the network I/O operations, and you can potentially manage buffer reads more flexibly.

@MdYasinAnsari could you please form an answer is if how to do so? I know how to do async reads but how do with batches?

@MdYasinAnsari could you pls give an answer on how to do so please?
